# Calculating the Riemann Zeta Function for x>2 real numbers

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, boost, numerical-methods

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <exception>

const int PRECISION = 100;
typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<PRECISION> > arbFloat;

// Prototypes
bool isStringValid(const std::string & str);
bool isNumberValid(const arbFloat & x);
inline std::string resizeArbtoString(const arbFloat & x);

int main(){
    arbFloat zeta = 0.0;

    std::cout << "\u03b6(s), s = ";
    std::string inputStr;
    std::getline(std::cin, inputStr);

    if(!isStringValid(inputStr)) return 2;

    arbFloat input = static_cast<arbFloat>(inputStr);
    if(!isNumberValid(input)) return 3;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(PRECISION);

    int i = 1;
    if(input == 0) {
        zeta = -0.5;
    } else {
        std::string preComp, postComp;
        std::cout << "Convergence:\n";
        do {
            preComp = resizeArbtoString(zeta);
            zeta += pow(i, -input);
            postComp = resizeArbtoString(zeta);
            std::cout << '\t' + preComp + '\n';
            i++;
        } while(preComp != postComp);
    }

    std::cout << "\n\u03b6(" + inputStr + ") = " << zeta << "\nAfter " << i << " iterations";

    return 0;
}

// Check input
bool isStringValid(const std::string & str){
    // Check if string contains spaces
    if(std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ') > 0){
        std::cout << "\nError: Input contains spaces\n";
        return false;
    }

    // Check if string contains multiple .
    if(std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), '.') > 1){
        std::cout << "\nError: Input contains multiple decimal marks\n";
        return false;
    }

    // Check if NaN or Out of bounds (due to parsing failure)
    try{
        boost::lexical_cast<arbFloat>(str);
    } catch(std::runtime_error){
        std::cout << "\nError: Unable to parse (value too large or incorrect number type)\n";
        return false;
    } catch(...){
        std::cout << "\nError: Input is NaN\n";
        return false;
    }

    // Check if intentional NaN
    if(boost::icontains(str, "nan")){
        std::cout << "\nError: Intentional NaN\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// Check number
bool isNumberValid(const arbFloat & x){
    // Range check
    if(x == std::numeric_limits<arbFloat>::infinity()){
        std::cout << "\nError: Out of bounds\n";
        return false;
    }

    if(x == 1){
        std::cout << "\nError: Complex Infinity\n";
        return false;
    }

    if(x < 2){
        std::cout << "\nError: Does not converge (unsupported)\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

inline std::string resizeArbtoString(const arbFloat & x){
    std::string resizedStr = static_cast<std::string>(x);
    resizedStr.resize(PRECISION + 2);
    return resizedStr;
}
```

## Explanation

This is used to calculate the [Riemann Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) for **real** numbers that are **greater than 2** (other than zero). **Smaller values will take much longer. This is a result of the algorithm I use for approximating the Riemann Zeta function, not due to implementation.** Likewise, larger values are much faster. If a larger value (around 500+) is entered, the precision of 100 digits is exceeded (it returns 1, but there are still digits past all those zeroes).

I am using three [Boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/): multi-precision, lexical cast, and string algorithms. First I initialize an arbitrary float with the precision of `100` (the value in the code will be manually changed occasionally). I am using function prototypes.

First I define the variable `zeta` to be zero. Then I get the user input (example output is below). I then check if it is a valid string that will convert easily to an `arbFloat` by using the `isStringValid` function. I use a string at first to catch things like multiple periods or spaces (and so on), which result in differing behavior.

I then convert it to an `arbFloat`, and check if that number is valid using the `isNumberValid` function. Next I set the output precision.

Inside of the if-else statement, I do the calculations. Inside of the else portion, I first convert the initial value of `zeta` to a string using the `resizeArbtoString` function. The string is being resized to `PRECISION + 2` to account for the number before the decimal mark, and the decimal mark itself.

I then do the actual calculations. Next, the resulting value of `zeta` is converted to a string using the same technique as before. The do-while loop checks if the strings are the same before and after calculations (if they are, it would result in an endless loop anyways).

Finally the value of `zeta` is printed along with the number of iterations.

## Example output

```
ζ(s), s = 100
Convergence:
        0
        1
        1.0000000000000000000000000000007888609052210118054117285652827862296732064351090230047702789306640624
        1.0000000000000000000000000000007888609052210118073520537827654190672617124639136733859843956171621636
        1.0000000000000000000000000000007888609052210118073520537827660413687894985780843877923897736295862226
        1.0000000000000000000000000000007888609052210118073520537827660413687896253431444106153299232999067602
        1.0000000000000000000000000000007888609052210118073520537827660413687896253431459412620374098062482047
        1.0000000000000000000000000000007888609052210118073520537827660413687896253431459412623465788470572268
        1.0000000000000000000000000000007888609052210118073520537827660413687896253431459412623465793379665733
        1.0000000000000000000000000000007888609052210118073520537827660413687896253431459412623465793379703381
        1.0000000000000000000000000000007888609052210118073520537827660413687896253431459412623465793379703382

ζ(100) = 1.000000000000000000000000000000788860905221011807352053782766041368789625343145941262346579337970338
After 12 iterations
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3s)
```

---

Am I doing something inefficiently? **How can I improve this code?**

Comment: You might be interested in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700003368

Comment: (My no-brainer: (doc)comment your code.)

Comment: @vnp I understand that there are some optimizations to the algorithm I am using to calculate the Riemann Zeta function, however these use higher-level calculus that is difficult to implement in C++. I suppose I am looking for optimizations to the actual program, not the mathematical equation. Thanks though!

Comment: (Per)Using [`boost/math/special_functions/zeta.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/math/blob/develop/include/boost/math/special_functions/zeta.hpp) is out of this question? A pity I can't read _math_: P.Borwein's [Efficient Algorithms for the Riemann Zeta Function](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P155.pdf)

Comment: @greybeard Haha, no. Even though I am using Boost, I want to calculate it without using the Boost Zeta function. And P. Borwein's document doesn't provide anything usable in C++ (it uses integrals and Bernoulli numbers and such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you noted that boost includes them in their headers, it's better to include them in your code too. That way, you know what features you're going to use. Include guards will make sure that there's no compile-time overhead.

Next, it's a little bit difficult to differentiate between the type `arbFloat` and your functions. Everything you've written uses camelCase. An IDE makes this simple, of course, but since all your names are available in a single file, it's a little bit overwhelming at first.

## Magic numbers

```
const int PRECISION = 100;
```

Here we see a great use of `const` to prevent a magic number. We don't have to guess what `100` means at another point in your code. We only see the identifier `PRECISION`.

However, you don't follow that approach with your error codes:

```
if(!isStringValid(inputStr)) return 2;

// ...

if(!isNumberValid(input)) return 3;
```

I suggest you to use a similar approach here, or an enum:

```
enum errorCode {
    INVALID_STRING = 2,
    INVALID_NUMBER = 3
};
```

## Keep the errors on the error stream

When a program has a lot of output, you usually pipe the output into a file:

```
echo "25" | ./zeta-program > zeta.dat
```

However, since all your error messages are also on `std::cout`, one will not see them. Use `std::cerr` instead of `std::cout` for errors.

## Your algorithm

There are some small things of with your algorithm. First of all, you display a string in *every* iteration. That's slow:

```
$ echo "25" | time ./zeta-program
... lots of output
0.00user 0.00system 1:06.21elapsed

$ echo "25" | time ./zeta-program > /dev/null
0.00user 0.00system 0:11.85elapsed
```

So maybe tone it down a little bit. Display the string every `n`th iteration. However, even the use of a string to compare the numbers is slightly weird. Transforming a number to base10 is usually slow compared to other artihmetic operations, *and* it doesn't cover your original intend.

Instead, write a function that does exactly what you want: check whether your value is close to your previous:

```
bool difference_is_small(const arbFloat & x, const arbFloat & y){
    using boost::multiprecision::pow;
    using boost::multiprecision::abs;

    static const arbFloat margin = pow(10, static_cast<arbFloat>(-PRECISION));
    return abs(x - y) <= margin;
}
```

With this function, we end up with

```
std::cout << "Convergence:\n";

arbFloat previous = 1;

while(!difference_is_small(previous,zeta)) {
    previous = zeta;
    zeta += pow(i, -input);    
    i++;
}
```

which clearly states what we're checking: the difference between the previous computation, and the following one. Note that you can still use your string-based comparison in `difference_is_small`, if you want to, but at that point it makes your code easier to read (and the check takes only 80% of the time your string-based check took).

Answer (score 1):

- In the convergence `do ... while`, why you are computing twice the
  same value between two iterations ?

  Call the first `preComp = resizeArbtoString(zeta);` before the `do {` and store the `postComp` in the next `preComp`.
- Don't forget to compute the `} while (...);` condition before changing the `preComp` :

  ```
     bool bContinue = true;

     preComp = resizeArbtoString(zeta);
     do {
         zeta += pow(i, -input);
         postComp = resizeArbtoString(zeta);
         std::cout << '\t' + preComp + '\n';
         // compute the while condition before
         bContinue = (preComp != postComp);
         // store the current postComp for the next iteration
         preComp = postComp;
         i++;
     } while(bContinue);
  ```

Comment: `why [compute the same value in two successive] iterations?` why compare `arbFloat`s using their truncated string representations in the first place? (For positive values,) comparing the (cheapest) logarithms of the current approximation and the absolute difference to its predecessor should do.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this answer improves the code, if anything it needlessly complicates it. Also, @greybeard I truncate the strings because the `arbFloat` has more precision (almost always 9 more digits) than my variable `PRECISION`. By truncating the string, it maintains the set precision and also decreases run time.

Comment: @Anonymous: I'm fully aware that you use the number of matching digits as a stand-in for logarithms - intentionally or not. I'm not ready to assume this as fast as using, say, logarithm base 2. I doubt it works in edge cases - 1.000000002(0²³²) vs. 1.000000001(9²³²) (meaning digit repeated _many_ times).

Comment: @greybeard Feel free to submit an answer, if you think it'll improve the code

Answer (score 1):

Since posting this question, I have found ways to optimize it on my own:

Regarding the `#include`s: It seems that there are excess `include`s, instead of having all of these:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <exception>
```

I really only need these:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
```

I assume this is because the Boost headers have subsequent `include`s that make the rest redundant. The functionality is the same.

---

For the do-while loop, instead of having:

```
do {
    preComp = resizeArbtoString(zeta);
    zeta += pow(i, -input);
    postComp = resizeArbtoString(zeta);
    std::cout << '\t' + preComp + '\n';
    i++;
} while(preComp != postComp);
```

This can be done with a for-loop, like so:

```
for(i = 1; i == 1 || preComp != postComp; i++){
    preComp = resizeArbtoString(zeta);
    zeta += pow(i, -input);
    postComp = resizeArbtoString(zeta);
    std::cout << '\t' + preComp + '\n';
}
```

It removes the extra line for `i++`, and keeps the `preComp != postComp` inherent in the loop. This does not use the techniques described in the other answers, but nonetheless.

---

*PS*: For negative even integers, the result is zero. I have since added this to the program. It isn't an optimization, but I figured since it could help future visitors, it should be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

(Not touching direct use of the Dirichlet series or stopping summation on the first difference between successive partial sums that is "too small in relation".)
The difference any given partial sum and the preceding one is the term just added.
Given that the range is from about 1.6 to 1.0, I suggest to just define a constant lower bound for terms to consider: `const arbFloat IGNORE("0.015e-"+PRECISION);` (syntax?)

```
    bool trace = true;
// don't bother computing pow(1, -input)
    arbFloat zeta = 1.0;
    int i = 2;
    if(input == 0) {
        zeta = -0.5;
    } else {
    // compute zeta from its series definition
        if (trace) std::cout << "Convergence:\n\t0\n\t1\n";
        do {
            const arbFloat term = pow(i, -input);
            zeta += term;
            if (trace) std::cout << '\t' + zeta + '\n';
            i += 1;
        } while (IGNORE < term);
    }
```

(If this worked (don't have a C++-environment I dare to try boost in), this would "trace" partial sums to the precision explicitly set, presumably.)